# laravel sql design

Tags: sql, laravel

Here is my table

```
Table Food
id    sub(foreign key Food.id)   name
1                                Apple
2      1                         Apple juice
3      2                         Apple juice product
4                                Orange
```

How can i got my result like?

if i search by id = 1, the result return id 1 ,2 ,3

if i search by id = 2, the result return id 1 ,2 ,3

if i search by id = 4, the result return id 4

Using loop? or any other way

i wanna to get all related to id = 1 using sub foreign key
id(2).sub is 1 and result include id(2), and id(3).sub also related to id(2), so that result include id(3)

Comment: "if i search by id = 2, the result return id 1 ,2 ,3" Shouldn't it be the case when you search with id = 3? Also why is both id=1 and id = 2 returns same answer. I don't understand your logic.

Comment: Yes. I'm also confused. Please explain answer in more detail

Comment: if i search by id = 1, the result return id 1 ,2 ,3

if i search by id = 2, the result return id 1 ,2 ,3

if i search by id = 4, the result return id 4

You didn't quite explain what you need, is this the result you wanna get or is it the result you're getting?

Comment: Have you tried the parent child concept with the use of eager loading + where condition inside it? Please check this link ]. It can help you to get idea . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28930251/need-to-set-a-1-to-many-relationship-in-the-same-table-in-laravel-4

Comment: i try my best to explain my logic.
Level 1: return first level, id:1, and got sub = null
Level 2, return all food which sub = 1, got id = 2
Level 3, return all food which sub = 2, got id = 3
Level 4, return all food which sub = 3, got id = null, then break.

Comment: I would suggest looking at nested sets: https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is `Parameter Grouping` https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#parameter-grouping

```
DB::table('food')
        ->where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('id', 1)
                  ->orWhere('sub', 1);
        })
        ->get();
```

Comment: the result only return id 1,2

Comment: id 2 related to id 1(sub = 1)
id 3 related to id 2(sub = 2)
i want id 1,2,3

Answer (score 1):

This can help you get the related data:

```
$lists_id = DB::table('food')
        ->where('id', $search_id)
        ->orWhere('sub', $search_id)
        ->lists('id')->toArray();

$sub_id = DB::table('food')
        ->where('id', $search_id)
        ->orWhere('sub', $search_id)
        ->lists('sub')->toArray();

$lists_id = array_merge($lists_id, $sub_id);

$food = DB::table('food')
        ->whereIn('id', $lists_id)
        ->orWhereIn('sub', $lists_id)
        ->get();
```